# Spring Boot Https startup failed

Tags: spring-boot, https, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have created spring boot application and tested my project with Rest API call its working fine.I'm applying SSL permission into my RestAPI but its giving exception.Please help me to solve my problem;

```
Java version: 10.2
Spring boot version:2.0.1
```

I have used below command to generate keyfile.

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcatssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks -validity 3650
```

[project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FaBv.png)

[application.yml https configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ev4O.png)

While starting my spring boot application I'm getting exception like below:

```
2019-02-26 17:28:47.726 ERROR 2796 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8082]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8082]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:256) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keystore password was incorrect
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2097) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 26 common frames omitted

2019-02-26 17:28:47.730  INFO 2796 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-26 17:28:47.742  INFO 2796 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-26 17:28:47.745 ERROR 2796 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8082 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8082, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-02-26 17:28:47.746  INFO 2796 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@112f364d: startup date [Tue Feb 26 17:28:44 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-26 17:28:47.748  INFO 2796 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-02-26 17:28:47.748  INFO 2796 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2019-02-26 17:28:47.749  INFO 2796 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-02-26 17:28:47.749  INFO 2796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown initiated...
2019-02-26 17:28:47.755  INFO 2796 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : masterdb-connection-pool - Shutdown completed.
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

source link Refernce:
https://code-adda.com/2018/06/enable-https-with-self-signed-certificate-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made mistake on keytool generation and I have created with againadmin privilege and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your key-store-password in application.yml is correct and match the password you entered when creating keystore?

Comment: Yes @Олег Гаврилів both password and alias name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot version with SSL:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

With this configuration I was able to configure SSL in my project.

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcatssl
server.ssl.key-password=tomcatssl
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Comment: I have used same configuration In my appplication.yml but I didn't use (security.require-ssl=true) because of Property 'security.require-ssl' is Deprecated in spring boot 2.0.